# Umbraco Razor - Script fails using Children.Random

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am having a weird issue, hoping you all have some pointers.  I am using Umbraco 4.11.10 and trying to fulfill a requirement to display 1 random quote from a collection of quotes.  The really puzzling thing is that this exact code works on a different site using the same version of Umbraco.
The Quote object only has two properties...quoteText and quoteSignature.  Here is my entire razor script (which currently fails).

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{
     var item = @Model.NodeById(1113).Children.Random();
     <div>
          <blockquote>@item.quoteText<span>- @item.quoteSignature</span></blockquote>
     </div>
}
```

If I strip out the div and block quote and all of that and just leave

```
var item = @Model.NodeById(1113).Children.Random();
```

it still fails.

If I remove Random() and output the @item variable it is a DynamicNodeList.  If I do something like..

```
foreach(var child in item)
{
     <div>
          <blockquote>@child.quoteText<span>- @child.quoteSignature</span></blockquote>
     </div>
}
```

It works, but of course I get all of the quotes.  So I guess that at least proves that the data is valid, and the property names are valid.  Just seems to be an issue using Random().  As I am pretty new to Razor I'm hoping this is just an oversight on my part.

**UPDATE **
The error from the error log is as follows

```
2013-09-03 19:34:00,142 [11] WARN  umbraco.macro - [Thread 24] Error loading MacroEngine script (file: CFRandomQuote.cshtml, Type: ''. Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Random'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at ASP._Page_macroScripts_CFRandomQuote_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\cf\macroScripts\CFRandomQuote.cshtml:line 5
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.ExecuteRazor(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
   at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.Execute(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
   at umbraco.macro.loadMacroScript(MacroModel macro)
   at umbraco.macro.renderMacro(Hashtable pageElements, Int32 pageId)
```

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Should that be `@child.quoteText` etc. in the code not `@item.`?

Comment: yep - copy paste error.  I updated the snippet - thanks!

Comment: Could you update the question with the error from the log files? There should be a stack trace showing what the error is. They're located at ~/app_data/logs/

Comment: thanks @Digbyswift - I added the error.  The important part of that message - 'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Random' - is perplexing as I know it does support random and has for awhile now.  An outdated RazorEngine dll perhaps?

Comment: after looking through the dll's I guess the newer builds don't use the RazorEngine.dll anymore.  It has System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll and System.Web.Razor.dll.  And on goes the search...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessarily a discrepancy in the DLLs. i've hecked through the v6 source and the `Random()` code is still there.

It's part of the `umbraco.MacroEngines.ExtensionMethods` class:

```
public static DynamicNode Random(this DynamicNodeList all)
{
    return all.Items.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
}
```

So the problem would seem to be that your macro is not referencing the namespace `umbraco.MacroEngines`. Put the following code into your macro, either before or after the `@inherits`:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
```

If this doesn't work then just implement the query long-hand:

```
@Model.NodeById(1113).ChildrenAsList
                     .OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())
                     .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Adding the @using did not resolve it, so I went with your long-hand approach, now I get this on save "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type".  I sure appreciate you hanging with me on this!  Thanks

Comment: Bit late, but do you have .net 4.5 installed? I'm seeing random not working on my production sites but on dev it works fine - Usually random (and other dynamically loaded extensions) fail when prerequisite dlls are failing to load (as they are dynamically resolved and dependencies need to be loaded)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var randomQuote = Library.NodeById(1113).ChildrenAsList.Items.GetRandom(1);
```

I think Model.NodeById is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by passing a number of items to return into the .Random() method. EG:

```
var galleryItems = imageGallery.Children.Random(50);
```

Or in your case (in theory):

```
var item = @Model.NodeById(1113).Children.Random(1);
```

However, if you do this, you'll receive a list with one item, so you probably need:

```
var item = @Model.NodeById(1113).Children.Random(1).Take(1);
```